# MAC input validation in SharePoint 2010 list

Tags: custom-form, validation

I would like to validate the input of a MAC address in a list and have gotten the formula 90% there. The final step that I'd like to accomplish is to set any upper-case characters to lower. I know this is achievable through the LOWER() function, but when used in conjunction with the rest of the formula it breaks. Here's what I'm working with:

```
=(LEN(MAC)=17)
+(MID(MAC,3,1)=":")
+(MID(MAC,6,1)=":")
+(MID(MAC,9,1)=":")
+(MID(MAC,12,1)=":")
+(MID(MAC,15,1)=":")
=6
```

It works quite simply of just checking for the colon-delimiter between each octet in the MAC. Is there a way to use LOWER() to enforce lower-case characters?

Comment: Are you trying to combine validation with calculation of a value?

Comment: No calculation. A manipulation though, if you will. Ultimately, I'd want to reject all formats that didn't conform to a strict MAC address format. I haven't found a way to lower the case of the input in the midst of these checks though.

Answer (score 0):

this can help:

```
=UPPER(LEFT(MAC,2)&":"&MID(MAC,3,2)&":"&MID(MAC,5,2)&":"&MID(MAC,7,2)&":"&MID(MAC,9,2)&":"&RIGHT(MAC,2))
```